# Magento 1 - Products not showing in secondary store?

Tags: product, configurable-product, magento-1, multistore

We are running on Magento 1.7 and have two stores.  We are looking to sell different products on the two different websites but a very select few products will be available on both.  In this example the "Single Heart Pendants"

**At Example1.com I have the following:**

[image]

**At Example2.com I have the following:**
[image]

When I got into the Admin Panel under, **Catalog-->Manage Products-->Select the Configurable Product** "Custom Make Your Own" I go to Categories thenI have this selected:
[image]

**and in manage stores I have:**

[image]

As proof that one of my products is there:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go To `Catalog > Manage Products` Edit the product you want to display in both.

In Left Tab **Website Option**  Check If you have selected both the websites

If its a configurable product check all its associated products have the website selected.

You can also Insure the following checklist why the product is not displayed in frontend

- The products must be Visible in Catalog.
- The products must be Enabled.
- Product must have a stock Quantity.
- The product must be set to In Stock.
- If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a
- stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
- The product must be assigned to the target Category.
- If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products
  through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target
  Website.
- You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

Comment: Ah this was the problem.  I didn't have the website set for all the simple products.  I thought if I enabled them for the configurable it would give the website to the simple products under them. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This drove me mad for hours as well for certain products. In my case I needed to reindex *Indexed category/products association* even if Magento did not say it needed reindexing.

Worth to be added to @Priyank check list!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a new root category for your secondary store

Catalog -> Categories -> Add Root Category

**Root Category Name:** New Store Default

Save this then go to System -> Manage Stores and click link under store name for your new store change **Root Category** to **New Store Default** and save

now your ready to add your new categories to the new store if you want to assign products to both stores when you assign categories them simply assign the products you want on both store to both category sets under each default store

Also under each product on the left hand side is a **Websites** tab simply select both store

Dont forget to Reindex your data

Comment: Hi again Dava! I added the Root Category that is what I "whited out on the image" and under system-->manage stores-->"whited out category"

Comment: I also reindexed and cleared the cache. note:I whited out the name so people wouldn't see the website name we just happened to name our root category the same as the website

Comment: @CodingMageSheen did you assign it to the new store also have u reindexed

Comment: Read the part about assigning to store and make sure it's done

Comment: Hmm in my last image isn't that how I assign the products to both store and category?

Comment: I can just create a new category that isn't the same name and post images I think I might be missing something

Comment: okay I updated the pictures

Comment: If you did what I said in my answer and updated you products to include in both stores then they should be showing

Answer (score 0):

in the product page (admin -> catalog -> manage products -> your product and scroll down to websites) have you associated it to your second store? ie both example1.com and example2.com ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I had to increase the quantity value. The quantity of my products was 0 that's why they didn't show up.